# Configure Videojs to use the local library

Tags: 8

Videojs in Drupal 8 gives the following error:

> Missing the Video.js library. Please download Video.js and extract it into the //vjs.zencdn.net/5.0 directory.

How can I configure Videojs to use local files? Where should I put Videojs files?

I think Videojs has not configuration interface.

Answer (score 2):

The [README.md](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/videojs/plain/README.md?id=refs/heads/8.x-1.x) included with the downloaded module says:

> 2. Download the Video.js library from http://videojs.com. Extract the module to `sites/all/libraries/video-js` and make sure that `sites/all/libraries/video-js/video.js` exists. NOTE: you can skip this step and use the Video.js version from the Video.js Content Delivery Network (CDN).

A comment in the documentation block in the module file suggests that the [Libraries API](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) determines where to places libraries.

> Defaults to videojs_directory when using the local file path location
>   or whatever location the Libraries API determines.

This location is also set by the videojs_directory configuration variable, which could be set by importing a YAML file via Configuration Management interface or with a tool such as [Drush](http://drush.org) or [Drupal Console](http://drupalconsole.com) despite the Video.JS module not having a specific configuration page.